# knowrob_omics & comp_ros not found

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with knowrob and so far everything works fine. The problem I have is related to knowrob_omics & comp_ros packages which are not included in knowrob.

I tried locating them using roslocate without any success. I am following the tutorials at the moment and they are packages that are referenced inside the tutorials.

I even tried by downloading roboearth but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39539/knowrob_omics-&-comp_ros-not-found/) by [George P](https://answers.ros.org/users/2902/george-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

those packages are not yet contained in the public distribution. Please send me an email (http://ias.cs.tum.edu/people/tenorth) and I can give you access to them.

best,
Moritz

P.S. Please tag future questions with "knowrob", then I'll get an email notifier whenever a new question is posted and my response times are faster.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just checked, comp_ros does not exist any more. We have moved the functionality into other packages such as [[comp_cop]] for reading perception results or [[tf_prolog]] for reading coordinate transformations from tf. The main reason was that the ROS access was only a minor part of the respective functionality, while the core part was what to do with the information obtained from ROS (which can, obviously, be of very different kind).

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1